# USSD output with portuguese characters in php

Tags: php, ussd

I am creating a USSD application, with Portuguese language,when trying to display menu for example 1.Transferéncia 2.Serviços 3.Transacçõesit 4.Informações displays on the phone 1.Transfer?ncia 2Servi?os *proximo without displaying other menu items. Is there a way of encoding this to diplay all the menu with as it is.

I have used this to change values received from the xml

```
$find = array('Ãª','Ã§','Ãµ','Ã³','Ã£','Ã¡', 'Ã©'); // en dash
$repl = array( 'é','ç' , 'õ', 'ó', 'ã', 'á', 'é');
$main = str_replace($find, $repl, $main);
$main = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $main);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclispe -

What's the encoding of the file in Eclipse set to? Right-click on the file in Eclipse, check under "Properties". It must be the same as in your meta-tag.

if you also using other IDE, then try to do the same.